# Specified cast is not valid in date nullable

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

I'm trying to store null value to a date datatype variable. The value is from my `DataSet` but I got the error Specified cast is not valid. Here's my code:

```
Dim varTimeOut As Nullable(Of DateTime) = DSMemberAttendance.Tables("tblMemberAttendance").Rows(iCounter)("TimeOut")
```

Is there any way to store empty value to my Date variable? I'm using Visual Basic 2005. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I only have VS 2015 but try if it works in 2005 too:
`Dim o As Object = DSMemberAttendance.Tables("tblMemberAttendance").Rows(iCounter)("TimeOut")
        Dim varTimeOut As Nullable(Of DateTime) = If(o IsNot Nothing, DirectCast(o, DateTime), Nothing)`

Comment: What's the actual data type of DSMemberAttendance.Tables("tblMemberAttendance").Rows(iCounter)("TimeOut") ?

Comment: @AlexB. I tried it but there's an error that says "End of statement expected" after the IF.

Comment: @AlexB the inline IF() didn't exist in VB 2005.  However the if shouldn't work anyway; if the object returned from the database is a DateTime it is a Struct and cannot be Nothing

Comment: What is the datatype of the TimeOut column in your MSAccess db?

Comment: It's Date/Time sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database code doesn't return Nothing for a NULL value in the database.  It instead returns a specific type (DBNull as I recall).  You need to specifically check for the database null (there may be an IsNull property on the database field) and set your Nullable appropriately in this case, only assigning the database value to the Nullable if it contains a valid date.

Answer (score 2):

In respect to Stuarts answer the following code snippet should do the trick:

```
    Dim varTimeOut As Nullable(Of DateTime)
    If DSMemberAttendance.Tables("tblMemberAttendance").Rows(iCounter).IsNull("TimeOut") Then
        varTimeOut = Nothing
    Else
        varTimeOut = DirectCast(DSMemberAttendance.Tables("tblMemberAttendance").Rows(iCounter)("TimeOut"), DateTime)
    End If
```

Comment: I tried to google the concept of casting... Since from my database, TimeOut is a Date/Time type, I'm looking for a way to display the value of varTimeOut without a Date in my DataGridView, with this format hh:mm:ss tt. Can you suggest any way to accomplish it? I tried to change the settings of my field's format in MSAccess but it doesn't help me either. Really thankful for your answer.

Comment: Goto DataGridView properties -> Columns [...] -> Chose your TimeOut column -> Open DefaultCellStyle [...] -> Format [...] -> Chose your favorite DateTime format